# why does this list-sorter crash?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, crash, logic

This page crashes on run:

```
<head>
<script>
    var list = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 19, 17, 15, 13, 11, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1];
    var listOrdered = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
    var loopCount = 0;

    while (list !== listOrdered) {
        if (list[loopCount] > list[loopCount + 1]) {
            var lower = list[loopCount + 1];
            var higher = list[loopCount];
            list[loopCount] = lower;
            list[loopCount + 1] = higher;
        }
        if (loopCount === 19) {
            loopCount = 0;
        } else {
            loopCount = loopCount + 1;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

</html>
```

What could i do to stabilize it?

As far as i am aware, the logic is as correct as i intend.
This is purely recreational experimentation.

After further development, the problem of comparison no longer exists:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    var sweeps = 0;
    var swaps = 0;
    var list = [25, 21, 4, 23, 32, 2, 40, 8, 27, 9, 29, 33, 31, 14, 12, 16, 35, 18, 37, 20, 39, 19, 38, 17, 36, 15, 34, 13, 6, 11, 30, 10, 28, 7, 26, 5, 1, 3, 22, 24];
    var loop = 0;
    var swapped = 0;
    var ordered = 0;

    while (ordered !== 1) {
        if (list[loop] > list[loop + 1]) {
            var lower = list[loop + 1];
            var higher = list[loop];
            list[loop] = lower;
            list[loop + 1] = higher;
            swapped = 1;
            swaps = swaps + 1;
        }
        if (loop === list.length - 1) {
            if (swapped === 0) {
                ordered = 1;
            }
            swapped = 0;
            loop = 0;
        } else {
            loop = loop + 1;
        }
        sweeps = sweeps + 1;
    }
    alert("list: " + list);
    alert("Sweeps: " + sweeps + ", Swaps: " + swaps);
</script>
```

(Like how “cooky monster” suggests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the array objects will never be the same object even if their contents end up the same (JavaScript doesn't compare values when using the comparison operators on objects (including arrays), but whether they are identical objects). You could serialize them both into a string and compare the strings, however, for a quick-and-dirty comparison that fits into your approach:

```
<head>
<script>
var list = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 19, 17, 15, 13, 11, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1];
var listOrdered = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
var loopCount = 0;

while (JSON.stringify(list) !== JSON.stringify(listOrdered)) {
    if (list[loopCount] > list[loopCount + 1]) {
        var lower = list[loopCount + 1];
        var higher = list[loopCount];
        list[loopCount] = lower;
        list[loopCount + 1] = higher;
    }
    if (loopCount === 19) {
        loopCount = 0;
    } else {
        loopCount = loopCount + 1;
    }
}
alert(JSON.stringify(list)) // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
</script></head></html>
```

`JSON.stringify` is not available by default in older browsers, so if you need to support older browsers, you can use https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a comparison, I'd just use a flag to indicate if you had to swap values during an iteration. If so, reset the counter to `0` and reset the flag. If not, you're done.

```
var list = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 19, 17, 15, 13, 11, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1];
var loopCount = 0;
var swapped;

while (true) {
    if (list[loopCount] > list[loopCount + 1]) {
        var lower = list[loopCount + 1];
        var higher = list[loopCount];
        list[loopCount] = lower;
        list[loopCount + 1] = higher;
        swapped = true;     // Set the flag indicating we swapped a pair of values.
    }
    if (loopCount === 19) { // At the end of a full iteration...
        if (swapped) {      //  check to see if we had occasion to swap..
            swapped = false;//  and if so, reset the flag, and start again..
            loopCount = 0;
        } else
            break; // or if not, we're done sorting.
    } else {
        loopCount = loopCount + 1;
    }
}
```

This will be much faster than any sort of array comparison.

Comment: i have been recommended to avoid while (true) loops for semantics. how important is this?

Comment: @Wetware.: It's purely a matter of preference. Others will suggest always putting all the logic in the block. Ultimately, because you're resetting the `loopCount` to `0` within the loop, you always run the risk of an infinite loop if the logic isn't correct. Your `ordered != 1` will work just fine as well, though I'd be inclined to use a boolean, but that also is just a matter of preference. :-)